# In-App Purchases Crashing App With No Internet Connection

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

My In-App Purchases is works perfect but if I my iPhone is not on Wi-Fi and using cellular connection with slow signal or without signal I'm getting this message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid product identifier: (null)'

Should I check Internet connection before enabling *buy* button? I hope there is easier way. All I need is to catch no connection error from `StoreKit.`

**Update**

For my In-App Purchases code I am using a little bit modified [this guide from raywenderlich.com.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) You also can download [the test project.](http://cdn1.raywenderlich.com/downloads/InAppRage2.zip)

My app is for iOS 8 and 7, and this tutorial is for iOS 6. Maybe it's a problem.

I only added `(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error` for catching error while restoring app and `SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred` case.

Comment: You should fix the cause of the error you posted. Your code doesn't appear to be doing proper result checking. And that should be done regardless of whether you do proper "reachability" checks or not.

Comment: @rmaddy I updated the question with the link to the source code. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Instead of asking people to download, build, and test your app, what you need to do is post just the relevant code in your question. The relevant code is the code actually causing the crash.

Answer (score 3):

Release the delegate in the `didFailWithError` method to prevent a crash:

```
- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to load list of products.");
    _productsRequest = nil;
    _completionHandler(NO, nil);
    _completionHandler = nil;

    request.delegate = nil; // Release the delegate
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Am I understand you right and releasing the delegate will kill broken SKRequest instance?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent this crash, I need to add some code inside this method which will prevent user to make a purchase.

```
- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to load list of products.");
    _productsRequest = nil;
    _completionHandler(NO, nil);
    _completionHandler = nil;
}
```

This works perfect while testing in Airplane mode. We need one more error handler in case Airplane mode will be turned off after showing In-App Purchases screen and turned on before tapping *buy.* And if the signal disappear during purchase.

We should handle `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` case:

```
- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
// failedTransaction
if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
{
    NSLog(@"Transaction error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
    // Update UI and / or post error message
}
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
```

}

You absolutly don't want to show alert when user taps *Cancel.*

I am also blocking *buy* button if following success  `BOOL` is not `YES.`

```
 requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products)
```